# Azure SQL Sync between Subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I have 2 subscriptions which have the same database and they would need to sync the data. Is this posible to achive with Azure SQL Sync.

Reason why we have 2 Subscriptions is becouse one of it is customers and other one is clients.

If this is not possible what would be the best way to sync 2 databses between azure subscriptions.

[Azure SQL data sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can as noted in Microsoft's [SQL Data Sync documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database#can-i-use-data-sync-to-sync-between-databases-in-sql-database-that-belong-to-different-subscriptions).

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot has changed  in 3 years :)

Comment: @DživoJelić maybe this should be the correct answer for this question now.

Answer (score 5):

This the answer provided by Microsoft Azure SQL Data Sync team:

> Thanks for contacting us. We do support sync databases across
>   subscriptions. (In fact, it is one of our use cases.)
>
> If the other subscription also belong to the same tenant, you can
>   directly add it by selecting a different subscription when adding
>   Azure database:

[image]

> Otherwise, probably it is better to use our PowerShell cmdlet
>   [New-AzureRmSqlSyncMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqlsyncmember?view=azurermps-5.3.0), you need to specify the
>   “MemberServerName” parameter, which is the fully qualified DNS name
>   for the logical server.
>
> To see the subscriptions in portal, they must under the same tenant
>   and the user needs to have permission to both of them. If that’s not
>   the case, they can add the sync member using PowerShell.

Comment: I just got the info if i am owner of both subscriptions that then its possible. Can you confirm this. Thx

Comment: I will share my answer with SQL Data Sync team to confirm, and I will let you know.

Comment: I have received an answer from Microsoft Azure SQL Data Sync and I will update my answer with the information provided. Thank you very much for requesting me to confirm.

Comment: I am admin on both subscriptions but i still dont see other subscription. What does it mean under same tenant ?

Comment: I found this. If you have previously signed up for an Azure subscription with your organizational account, you already have a tenant! In the Azure portal, you should find a tenant when you navigate to "All services" and "Azure Active Directory." You are free to use this tenant as you see fit.My account is @outlook.com i need a domain email ?

Comment: I don't know much about subscriptions. Please open a ticket since is free for subscription related questions/issues. Go to "View my Bill" click on the top right corner of Azure Portal, then on the left vertical panel click on "New support request".