# Store Azure SQL DB Long Term backups in another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-backup-vault

When a SQL Server is deleted in Azure. The corresponding databases and backups are also deleted. This is a big security issue if an admin login is compromised.

We want to store our long term backups (weekly) on another subscription and therefore two logins would need to be compromised for all of our data to be deleted.

How can I push the db long term backups to another subscription and can Azure automate this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to move your backups to another subscription. You can prevent an Azure SQL Database server can be deleted using Azure Locks as explained [here](https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2017/10/21/azure-resource-locks-to-avoid-accidental-deletes/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources#portal). You can put a lock on the resource groups that contain any Azure SQL logical server.

You can also put a resource lock on the vault.

Comment: Locks can be removed by users with admin privileges, most likely the same admin that can delete the sql server. Therefore there is still an issue of the server being deleted

Comment: One Azure customer contacted me on Facebook two months ago because one of his developers accidentally deleted a resource group with all their database servers. With a lock in place, at least his developer would not be able to say the removal was accidental. Their company was not productive for 6 days and almost lost all their customers.

Comment: Yes, that sounds terrible and the exact scenario we don't want to go through. If we had the db backups in another subscription then we would be back up a lot quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't configure log term backup to point to another subscription. But, as a workaround you can set up data sync to sync your data to another subscription: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data
here is a related question:
[Azure SQL Sync between Subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301691/azure-sql-sync-between-subscriptions)

Or another cheaper solution is to write a PowerShell script to back up your DB and save the BACPAC to the other subscriptions BLOB storage:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-powershell you can easily call this PowerShell script from an Azure Automation account.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the long term retention backups will be deleted if you delete the server, those backups are associated with the subscription.